# Book recommendation for studying functional equations

Tags: functions, inequality, soft-question, contest-math, book-recommendation

I am a student who is just starting high school and am very interested in taking part in the IMO (International Mathematical Olympiad). I am currently reading about inequalities. Having studied many of the classical inequalities, I have found that a good knowledge of functions and functional equations would be very beneficial. However, the books I have looked up seem very complicated and I have not found any book offering a friendly introduction into the subject for beginners. None of what I have looked up also relate to olympiad problems. Can anyone please recommend me a book that could help me get acquainted with the topic. Thanks.

Comment: You might find http://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=338 useful, but I almost always turn to http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/fe.htm and especially http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/fe/fe-toc3.htm

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272591/functional-equation-book-for-olympiad and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241445/books-on-functional-equations

Comment: @Henry I have checked the links, IMO math is providing problem-solving techniques (assuming you have prior knowledge). Also the other two links are giving more of a handout, listing and summing up the important parts. But I would like a good book to really understand the topic, and maybe also through exercises. I.e. I don't really know where all the equations in the last two links came from. I really need to understand the topic so that I could eventually solve problems, Olympiad level. I really appreciate your help but I just wanted to make it clear for anyone else who might want to answer.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the last comment. I think it would be helpful.

Comment: Functional Equations and how to solve them - Christopher G Small, is totally awesome.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I have looked it up and it is quiet simple, and awesome. I have also found this book, problem solving strategies by Engel. It provides a good introduction into many topics including functional  equations.

Comment: Can anyone have some pdf of books about functional equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Since you put the focus on *inequalities* I'd like to point to
*[The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052154677X)* by J. Michael Steele. This book gives a comprehensive treatment of inequalities from many different perspectives. It is both, instructive and a pleasure to read. If you don't know it, it might provide you with a lot of nice gems.

> A valuable,  systematical primer into  functional  equations  is      *[Introduction  to Functional   Equations](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821853147)* by Costas Efthimiou. It  also provides IMO examples. Maybe it is even online available.